# Why does my code not like this variable? Why is else not working?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

Python 3.7 issue.

I'm writing a D&D Character sheet layout with calculators for the inputs. The idea is that if something happens to the character I can update the layout to include it. Such as loss of HP.

So the stats are in a loop and when you get to the end it asks for inputs to update it in the next refresh.

But when I try to write a variable for this particular area it carks it.

And the else statement (also tested on other code) also is hated by the program and when I remove it I get EOF errors.

TL;DR Else statement doesn't work. Variable doesn't work.

Said variable I have changed 3 times and run it on other code with it working fine same with the else.

```
update = input("Update? ")
    if update == "Long Rest":
        HP = (8+CM + ((Level-1)*(HitDice+CM)
    else:
        print (" ")


    repeat = input("Continue? ")
    if repeat == "Finish":
        Finished = True
    else:
        Finished = False
```

Finished is a while loop

Whenever I try to run the code I get a pop up box saying "Invalid Syntax". My computer won't let me run the code due to the syntax error.

I'm kind of new to coding but I did look for a similar answer but all the ones I found didn't work.

Comment: 1. Your indentation is off. 2. The third line is missing quite a few parentheses

Comment: If you get an error, please include the exact error message and traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Everything after the first line should be unindented by one.
2. The 3rd line doesn't close all the brackets.
3. Not a syntax issue, but the standard is not to have a space between a function and its arguments.

   - i.e `print (" ")` becomes `print(" ")`
4. Why do you need to print a space, why not just a new line?

---

```
update = input("Update? ")
if update == "Long Rest":
    HP = (8 + CM + ((Level - 1) * (HitDice + CM)))
else:
    print()

repeat = input("Continue? ")
if repeat == "Finish":
    Finished = True
else:
    Finished = False
```

Comment: @Cyfrwys Assuming `CM`, `Level`, and `HitDice` are already defined, this works fine for me. What's the issue?

Comment: Fixed it! I went through it again and the variable that didn't work was the repeat one because of missing that single bracket (Removing the else gave me that problem). Thank you so much for helping me. I'm sorry I wasted your time on such a simple issue.